# Big query table update from reference CSV file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a BigQuery table and I want to update the content of few rows it from a reference CSV file. This CSV file is uploaded to Google cloud storage bucket.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You're expected to [try to solve your problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5698098). If you get stuck somewhere then it's a good idea to ***ask a specific question*** here based on your own solution attempt. So far it's unclear what's preventing you from solving this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use [external table from storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage), you can only read the CSV, not update them.

However, you can [load you CSV into a BigQuery native table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv), [perform the update with DML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language), and then [export the table to CSV](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data). That only works if you have only one CSV.

If you have several CSV files, you can, at least, print the [pseudo column `_FILE_NAME` to identify the files](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#the_file_name_pseudo_column) where  you need to perform the change. But the change will have to be performed manually or with the previous solution (native table)